# Could not analyse class: maybe not loaded or no autoloader in typo3 for export using phpexcel

Tags: typo3, phpexcel, extbase, typo3-7.6.x

I am writing an export feature using phpexcel library. I have included the library into `typo3conf/ext/extension_name/Classes/Library/PHPExcel`. And also included the file `typo3conf/ext/extension_name/Classes/Library/PHPExcel.php`. And injected this file into my typo3 extbase controller as

```
/**
* PHPExcel
*
* @var \VendorName\ExtensionName\Classes\PHPExcel
* @inject
*/
protected $PHPExcel;
```

And called this into my export function as

```
public function exportxlsAction() {
    $objPHPExcel = new \PHPExcel();
}
```

On clicking the backend module it throws the error as

```
Could not analyse class: "VendorName\ExtensionName\Classes\PHPExcel" maybe not loaded or no autoloader? Class VendorName\ExtensionName\Classes\PHPExcel does not exist..
```

Why is it so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problems in your namespace. Just change it like below.

```
\VendorName\ExtensionName\Classes\PHPExcel to \VendorName\ExtensionName\Library
```

Also if you have added all PHPExcel library on this path `\VendorName\ExtensionName\Classes\Library\PHPExcel` then your name space like below.

```
\VendorName\ExtensionName\Library\PHPExcel
```

**Another Way**.

In your `ext_emconf.php` File. add below code.

```
'autoload' => [
    'classmap' => [
      'Classes',
      'Classes/Library/PHPExcel/PHPExcel.php',
   ]
]
```

Your controller file code like below.

```
/**
* PHPExcel
*
* @var \PHPExcel
* @inject
*/
protected $PHPExcel = null;
```

And you function as it is. like below.

```
public function exportxlsAction() {
    $objPHPExcel = $this->PHPExcel;
}
```

After replace this changes you need to once install/Uninstall Extension.

Comment: Now gives the following error :: Class 'VendorName\ExtensionName\Library\PHPExcel_Calculation' not found

Comment: in whitch path you have included this file.

Comment: In this path typo3conf/ext/extension_name/Classes/Library/PHPExcel/Calculation.php,  that file is included.

Comment: With require_once it  is working. I just need to change that method. Was trying with typo3 injection method. But that is not working.